# VBA incorrectly copying data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to copy data from one sheet and paste it into another sheet as values. The code should paste the new data 2 rows below any existing data in the destination sheet.

My code currently places data in the correct position. However, it is not copying the data from the source sheet. It is instead copying the destination sheet name and I am not sure why.

```
Sub CopyAndPasteData()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    ' Set the source and destination worksheets
    Set wsSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDestination = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    ' Find the last row with data in column A of the destination sheet
    lastRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Copy values from rows A106:A110 of the source sheet
        wsDestination.Cells(lastRow + 2, 1).Resize(5, 1).Value = wsSource.Range("A106:A110").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Btw the `Application.CutCopyMode = False` is unnecesssary - you're not using the clipboard to begin with. Also, unable to reproduce.

Comment: @BigBen Noted and removed - thank you. I have also tried to replicate it in a new workbook and it is not working. In fact it copies nothing and throws no errors. Do you have any ideas on a solution or alternative logic?

Comment: If the macro is in the same workbook as the sheets prefix `Worksheets()` with `ThisWorkbook` eg `Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: @CDP1802, thank you. But the same issues persists.

Comment: What is the value in for example A106, is it a value or formula ?

Comment: @CDP1802 All formulas. The length is dynamic, which is why I am copying the whole row.

Comment: You're not copying a whole row, you're copying a vertical set of five cells in the A column (A106:A110). If I run your code, it does exactly that; I'm not getting sheet names.

Comment: As @Paul has said you’re not copying a row you’re copying five cells.  What does the formula do?  This code won’t copy the formula it’ll copy the values of them when it runs.  Try adding in a ‘wsDestination.Cells(lastRow + 2, 1).Resize(5, 1).select’ At the end to check that it is outpouring to the right place (this code should then be removed when you are confident it’s going to the right place